# How do I convert loop await to Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I'm converting some old code from a colleague, I'm not new to Javascript but I am rusty and I am new to Promises, Map and other new JS features.

I need to convert a `for` loop with an `await` to a `Promise` that can be used in a bigger Promise chain.

I think the answer is in `Promise.all` and a `Map / Stream / Reduce` (I'm still learning which is for what) but all of the medium articles I've looked at are poorly explained (and I probably don't know the right thing to search for).

Here is the code I am converting:

```
//foos and bars are global and can be used in the `then` after this promise resolves, 
//  so what the promise returns is unimportant

for (let bar of bars) {
    foos[bar] = await new MyClass(bar).myAsyncOperation();
}
```

**How do I convert the loop so that the promise does not resolve until all items in the loop have finished?**

Also, should I be converting `myAsyncOperation` to return a Promise or can/should I leave it as an async function?

Comment: that's how you do it ... the async function this loop is in won't resolve until all promises in the loop resolve

Comment: for..of will not finish until the promises are all resolved already

Comment: Remember since I'm moving that code inside a new Promise, it's not async, so I can't use await. Is what you've both commented still true in that case?

Comment: It’s not possible to say if you should convert `myAsyncOperation` because we don’t see the code of it and from the outside it makes absolutely no difference. An `async` function is just a function that returns a promise implicitly. Though generally speaking, going from async-await to explicit promises is seen as a step backwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a new array of Promises from your `bars`, ideally using [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and then pass that array to [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)
to get their results.

```js
// Wrap main code in an async IIFE so we can use await.
(async () => {
  let bars = [1,2,3,4]

  // Sample async function which implicitly returns a Promise since it's marked
  // as async. Could also be a regular function explicitly returning a Promise.
  const myAsyncOperation = async bar => bar * 5

  // Create an array of Promises from bars.
  const tasks = bars.map(bar => myAsyncOperation(bar))

  try {
    // Pass the Promises to Promise.all and get results.
    const results = await Promise.all(tasks)

    console.log(results)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
})()
```

The difference from your [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) example is that `Promise.all` doesn't wait for each separate Promise to resolve before moving on to the next one. It's more or less parallel rather than sequential.

> ... Also, should I be converting myAsyncOperation to return a Promise or
>   can/should I leave it as an async function?

Well, If `myAsyncOperation` is an [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) marked function then it *already* returns a `Promise`. Marking a function as `async` causes it to always implicitly return a `Promise`.

Comment: So `return Promise.all( bars.map(foo => new MyClass(foo).myAsyncOperation()) );` ? Ah yes, I see that's what the other guy answered

Comment: @NickCardoso Exactly.

Comment: Ah but what I'm missing then is that each async op should update an element of array. Is that possible?

Comment: `Promise.all` will return a new array. If you want to update the original `bars` array then just reassign, i.e `bars = results`, or just loop through `results` using [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and use the `index` argument to assign to the corresponding element in the original array, i.e `results.forEach((result, index) => {bars[index] = result})`

Comment: I had the wrong simplification above, just updated my code - two arrays in use. Would i need a second loop to do the assignment, or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: @NickCardoso I've edited my last comment, see if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't because I need to assign each mapped result to an element in another array with (lets say) the same key

Comment: Assuming your `otherArray` has the same elements as `bars` (and in the same order), you could just do `results.forEach((result, index) => { otherArray[index] = result })`

Comment: Ok, but because I want to return Promises.all, I have do do this results loop in the then - correct? There's no way to do it all together, right

Comment: Yeah... or you could just do `const results = await Promise.all(tasks)` and do the loop/forEach on the next line. Remember you can `await` Promises, and `Promise.all` returns a `Promise`.

Answer (score 4):

`Promise.all` is the way to go:

```
Promise.all(bars
  .map(foo => new MyClass(foo).myAsyncOperation()))
    .then(results => {
      console.log(results)
    }
  );
```